# How to set tomorrow in a date or timestamp column

Tags: sql, postgresql

Suppose I have a table with a date of timestamp column. In that column there should always be tomorrow. How do you do that?

Comment: If it is **always** tomorrow, don't store it at all. Create a view that returns `current_date + 1` for that column

Comment: Do you mean existing table data should be updated each and every day, to tomorrow's date?

Answer (score 7):

You could set the following to the column when you create the table

```
ColumnName DATE DEFAULT CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day',
```

However if you have already created the table, you could add
    CURRENT_DATE + INTERVAL '1 day' 
when you inserting.

Answer (score 2):

default value for inserting new rows:
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/ddl-default.html

time calculation functions
http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/interactive/functions-datetime.html

... 2 minutes research ...

Answer (score 1):

try

in column define set **not null and default values current_date + interval '1 day'**